# Finding a sequence $a_n$ that diverges such that $\|a_n\|$ converges (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

Finding a sequence $a_n$ that diverges such that $\|a_n\|$ converges (in $\mathbb{R}$)

I am having a hard time finding an example that works. An example or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What norm is $||.||$ - do you just mean the absolute value? If so, just consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: A hint is that I think they mean "the limit of $a_n$ does not exist" or "$a_n$ does not converge" when they say "$a_n$ diverges." (I typically think of something that "diverges" as something that goes to infinity in some sense, but that is not happening here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a_n = (-1)^n$. It does not converge but $\|a_n\| = 1, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.